# So trying to implement simple token swap uniswap but keep getting error Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Reverted]

Tags: web3js, uniswap

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.10;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "./exchanges/uniswap/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";
import"./interfaces/IERC20.sol" ;
contract swap is Ownable {
     using SafeMath for uint256;
     uint deadline = block.timestamp + 300;  
      IUniswapV2Router02 public immutable uniswapV2Router;
  IUniswapV2Router02 public immutable sushiSwapRouter;
  constructor(address _uniswapRouterProvider,  address _sushiSwapProvider) public {
        uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(_uniswapRouterProvider);
    sushiSwapRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(_sushiSwapProvider);
     
} 

function uniSwap(uint amountIn,  address  _assetIn , address _assetOut) public onlyOwner returns (bool) {
    address[] memory path = new  address[](2);
      path[0] = _assetIn;
      path[1] = _assetOut;
      
     uint[] memory amounts = uniswapV2Router.getAmountsOut(amountIn, path);
        uint amountOut = amounts[amounts.length - 1];
    IERC20 token = IERC20(path[0]);
    require(token.approve(address(uniswapV2Router), amountIn), "FlashSwap: Failed to approve");
    uniswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForTokens(amountIn, amountOut, path,  address(this), deadline);
    return true; }
}
```

Javascript to interact with token ;

```
const { ethers } = require("ethers");
const Web3 = require("web3")
const fs = require('fs');
const {BigNumber,  FixedFormat,   FixedNumber,formatFixed    parseFixed , BigNumberish } = require("@ethersproject/bignumber");
  
require('dotenv').config();
const network = "kovan";
const provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider(network, {
    
    infura: {
     projectId: process.env.INFURA_API_KEY2,
  
    
   },
});
//const mnemonic = fs.readFileSync("secret").toString().trim();
const mnemonic = process.env.mnemonic ;
walletMnemonic = new ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic(mnemonic);
wallet = walletMnemonic.connect(provider);
Usdt_address = '0x07de306FF27a2B630B1141956844eB1552B956B5';
ierc20_abi =  require('./build/contracts/IERC20.json').abi 
Usdt_Contract = new ethers.Contract(Usdt_address,ierc20_abi,wallet);
Dai = "0x4F96Fe3b7A6Cf9725f59d353F723c1bDb64CA6Aa"
const fiveGwei = BigNumber.from("59000000000");
options = {gasPrice: fiveGwei, gasLimit: 2700000}
const amountIn = Web3.utils.toWei('9000000000', 'ether');
  Usdt_Contract.transfer(swap_address, numberOfTokens,options).then(function(tx) {
      console.log(tx);
  })

const swap = async() => {
  // const swap2=  swap_contract.uniSwap(
  //   amountIn  ,
  //   Usdt_address ,
  //   Dai,
  //   options)

}
swap();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the deadline in the contract body

```
uint deadline = block.timestamp + 300;
```

That's equivalent to setting in the constructor.

It's better to initialize deadline in the same function that calls to uniswap.

```
function uniSwap(uint amountIn,  address  _assetIn , address _assetOut) public onlyOwner returns (bool) {
    // 
    uint deadline = block.timestamp + 300;

    // .. other operations here

    uniswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForTokens(amountIn, amountOut, path,  address(this), deadline);

}
```

Remove any reference to deadline in the contract body.

Comment: So i  done what you told  me to do but code still fails when i try to swap tokens on uniswap . This is the  tx has on kovan ether scan  Txhash : 0xed0547d8932dca98b46aa721e275330f6476da5391bdfc6225908f226b648f0b

Comment: i'm really confused , i've tried to  do everything but i cant seem to swap tokens

Comment: @deficoder From the [transaction trace](https://kovan.etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0xed0547d8932dca98b46aa721e275330f6476da5391bdfc6225908f226b648f0b&type=parity) it fails when your contract tries to access USDT funds from the router. Why are you trying to transferFrom from the router address? That isn't going to work.

Comment: i'm confused can you please look at my code above and tell me what i need to fix  . the code above that is .

Comment: @deficoder From the trace the call that fails has signature `23b872dd` which is [transferFrom](https://www.4byte.directory/signatures/?bytes4_signature=23b872dd). The trace doesn't match the source of question so either the wrong bytecode was deployed or it is calling the wrong contract address. Check the correct bytecode is deployed and the correct address is used.